# SQL Server: how to insert random integers into table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a test table like this

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    rid INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    val INT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_temp_rid PRIMARY KEY (rid)
);
```

What are the different methods in SQL Server to insert random integers into this table (e.g for 1000 rows). While loop, cross join or what?

I tried this but the result is not correct

```
DECLARE @val AS INT = 1;

WHILE @val <= 1000
    BEGIN
        INSERT #temp (val)
        SELECT RAND(@val);
        SET @val = @val + 1;
    END

SELECT *
FROM   #temp;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `select CAST(RAND() * 1000000 AS INT) AS [RandomNumber]` for generating or selecting random integers .
so the full query will be something like that :

```
    DECLARE @t TABLE( randnum float )
DECLARE @cnt INT; SET @cnt = 0
WHILE @cnt <=10000
BEGIN
SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
INSERT INTO @t
SELECT RAND( (DATEPART(mm, GETDATE()) * 100000 )
+ (DATEPART(ss, GETDATE()) * 1000 )
+ DATEPART(ms, GETDATE()) )
END
SELECT randnum, COUNT(*)
FROM @t
GROUP BY randnum
```

regards..

Comment: Thanks for pointing out select CAST(RAND() * 1000000 AS INT) AS [RandomNumber]

Comment: If you are doing this repeatedly you will get many **identical** "random" numbers because the parameter to RAND is a *seed*, and the *seed* will be unchanged until the current millisecond changes.  Most systems can insert many records per millisecond.

Answer (score 10):

This also done above

```
Insert Into @t
Select Cast(rand(checksum(newid()))*1000000  as int)
go 1000
```

See this link : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1467/populate-a-sql-server-column-with-a-sequential-number-not-using-an-identity/

Comment: I added this link that I fill the solution you got from here, please update or remove if this is not correct

Answer (score 7):

From [SQL SERVER – Random Number Generator Script](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/29/sql-server-random-number-generator-script-sql-query/):

```
SELECT randomNumber, COUNT(1) countOfRandomNumber
FROM (SELECT ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(6)) % 1000) + 1 randomNumber
      FROM sysobjects) sample
GROUP BY randomNumber;
```

**EDIT**: Just to clarify, the script is grouping on the random number that was generated per row. So the total number of results is not guaranteed. You can be sure you'll never get more rows than `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sysobjects`, though.

Answer (score 2):

I think a `while is going to work. You are very close.

```
DECLARE @val AS INT = 1;

WHILE @val <= 1000
BEGIN
    INSERT #temp (val)
    SELECT cast((RAND()*1000) as int);
    SET @val = @val + 1;
END

SELECT *
FROM   #temp;
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out after @Tamer's suggestion